# Bower no such file or directory: /opt/local/bin/bower

Tags: node.js, npm, bower, bower-install

I have uninstalled macport and trying homebrew. After installing node using brew. I installed bower which didn't give any error.

```
    $npm install -g bower
    => ~/npm-global/bin/bower -> ~/npm-global/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower
    => ~/npm-global/lib
```

After installation, I tried bower which errors out

```
    $bower
    => no such file or directory: /opt/local/bin/bower
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Earlier I have run into the following issue.
https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1335

As part of fix I had an alias in my ~/.zshrc
alias bower='noglob /opt/local/bin/bower'

I had to change that to 
alias bower='noglob bower'